# how to use scanf to read an integer from the command line

Tags: c, scanf

suppose I have the following code:

```
int number;
scanf("%d", number);
printf("%d", number);
```

I am entering a number, say 10, as the input, but I am not getting it to print anything. If I change my code so that it scans the input as a string it works fine:

```
char number[2];
scanf("%s", number);
printf("%s", number);
```

Am I doing something wrong? And if so, what? I am doing all my work at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler if that changes anything

Comment: `scanf(%d", &number)`. Not posting this as an answer because the question is bound to be a duplicate.

Comment: I get a segmentation fault when I do that

Comment: Read *carefully* the [documentation of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of *every* function you are using. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: BTW, you'll better install some (free) C compiler on your own computer (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)). And use it on the command line. Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm reading over the documentation and am unsure of what exactly I'm looking for. I haven't seen anything that suggests why I would be getting the segmentation fault. Are you suggesting that it is the website I am using that is at fault? Or is it still an error with my code.

Comment: I strongly recommend compiling on your own computer, if your goal is to learn programming in C. Of course your own code is buggy, but you don't show any [MCVE] in your question. So install [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on your machine (if on Windows, use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)...), and compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info).

Comment: You may find [Requesting User Input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471846/requesting-user-input-in-c/52472062#52472062) helpful.

Comment: Your second code snippet, with `scanf("%s", number);`, almost certainly has undefined behavior. `scanf` with a `%s` format reads an arbitrarily long string into the target. You defined `number` as an array of just 2 characters, and one of those is needed to hold the terminating `'\0'` null character. If you enter `10`, you're storing beyond the end of your array. That has undefined behavior. If you're **unlucky** it will appear to work (I say "unlucky" because it means you have an undetected bug).

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the address of `number` to `scanf`: `scanf("%d", &number);`

The reason that it works when you use a string is because a string in c is really just a pointer to a `char`, and `printf`knows that, for a string, it needs to dereference the pointer to get to the `chars` of the string.

Comment: when I do that I get a segmentation fault

Comment: @JohnDoe As already stated in the comments: Provide a [mcve] in your Question.

Comment: it is all of those. The code above is all I have written inside of the main method

Comment: @JohnDoe: Your question does not include a [mcve]. If it did, I'd be able to copy the code from your answer, paste it into a source file on my computer, and compile and run it. An MCVE includes the definition of the `main` function and all required `#include` directives.

Comment: @JohnDoe: When I copy the code from your question, add the missing `&`, and add the lines needed to turn it into a complete program, it works on my system. The problem must be in something you haven't shown us.